# Outlook - prevent ability to reply based on criteria

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have an email address with my college. I rarely get emails there, but they are important so I need to respond when they come.  The college's email system doesn't offer IMAP or POP, but it does allow me to forward the emails.  I forward them to my gmail account which is IMAP'ed into my Outlook.

When I reply to the emails, I want the replies to come from my college email address, which means I have to go to the college's email website to compose and send the replies.  The problem is that when I read them in Outlook, half the time I forget and reply from Outlook, which means my reply comes from my gmail address instead of the account the email was sent to.

How can I disable/prevent the ability to reply to those emails from Outlook?

**Update:**  Someone below suggested that I change the "From" and "Reply To" address on the emails instead of blocking replies/forwards from being sent.  This would be great if it could be automated, because otherwise I'd still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you don't.  Instead, configure Outlook to stick in the college address in the "From" and "Reply-To" headers.

Comment: That sounds like a great solution.  How would I do that?

Comment: I've looked into this and if it couldn't be done automatically then I'd still have the same problem.  I need an automatic solution...

Comment: You can just change the "e-mail address" option in your account settings.  Your "e-mail address" will be the university e-mail address, but your IMAP username and server will be g-mail.

Comment: Then I would need a dedicated address because the setting you're talking about would affect all emails in that account, if I understand you.

Comment: It isn't clear from your question that you wanted to prevent reply only to a subset of incoming emails.  It sounded as if you wanted replies to any gmail message to appear to come from the college account.  I think changing the reply address could be automated, but you'd need to write some VB-for-Applications code to do it.  And you'd have to be very specific on the rule for determining which emails are affected.